# jqplot canvas into PDF using iText

Tags: canvas, pdf-generation, jqplot, itext7

Is there a way to render jqplot canvas (HTML page) into a PDF file. I am using iText7 and pdfHTML2.0.0. Currently I am converting the canvas elements into an image using DataURL but that leads to a poor resolution of image when compared to the canvas on the web page. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sparks245/uhxqdta6/4/) for webpage (with dataURL) [Fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/Sparks245/d9ogpeh2/2/) for webpage (with canvas) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SECSlu3AsqK-Y0SRvfnqyklKlQhQDIu9/view?usp=sharing) is the output PDF

If I use pdfHTML directly with the canvas elements it shows a white space in its place in PDF.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The below code is used for canvas to image conversion (Offsets have been modified to allow the labels to fit inside the image):

```
function jqplotToImgBase(pElementID)
{
    var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    newCanvas.width = $('#'+pElementID).find("canvas.jqplot-base-canvas").width() + 60;
    newCanvas.height = $('#'+pElementID).find("canvas.jqplot-base-canvas").height()+ 70;
    var baseOffset = $('#'+pElementID).find("canvas.jqplot-base-canvas").offset();
    baseOffset.top = baseOffset.top - 30;
    baseOffset.left = baseOffset.left - 20;

    // make white background for pasting
    var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height);
    $('#'+pElementID).children().each(function () {
    // for the div's with the X and Y axis
        if ($(this)[0].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'div') {
            // X axis is built with canvas
            $(this).children("canvas").each(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                newCanvas.getContext("2d")    .drawImage(this,
                    offset.left - baseOffset.left,
                    offset.top - baseOffset.top - 10
                );
            });
            // Y axis got div inside, so we get the text and draw it on the canvas
            $(this).children("div").each(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");
                context.font = $(this).css('font-style') + " " + $(this).css('font-size') + " " + $(this).css('font-family');
                context.fillStyle = $(this).css('color');
                context.fillText($(this).text(),
                    offset.left - baseOffset.left,
                    offset.top - baseOffset.top + $(this).height() - 10
                );
            });
        } else if($(this)[0].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'canvas') {
            // all other canvas from the chart
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            newCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this,
                offset.left - baseOffset.left,
                offset.top - baseOffset.top - 10
            );
        }
    });
    // add the point labels
    $('#'+pElementID).children(".jqplot-point-label").each(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");
        context.font = $(this).css('font-style') + " " + $(this).css('font-size') + " " + $(this).css('font-family');
        context.fillStyle = $(this).css('color');
        context.fillText($(this).text(),
            offset.left - baseOffset.left,
            offset.top - baseOffset.top + $(this).height()*3/4 - 10
        );
    });

    // add the pie chart point labels
    $('#'+pElementID).children(".jqplot-pie-series.jqplot-data-label").each(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");
        context.font = $(this).css('font-style') + " " + $(this).css('font-size') + " " + $(this).css('font-family');
        context.fillStyle = $(this).css('color');
//        context.fillText($(this).text(),
//            offset.left - baseOffset.left + 15,
//            offset.top - baseOffset.top + $(this).height()*3/4 - 10
//        );
        context.wrapText($(this).text(),
            offset.left - baseOffset.left + 15,
            offset.top - baseOffset.top + $(this).height()*3/4 - 10,
            110,
            10
        );
    });
    // add the title
    $('#'+pElementID).children("div.jqplot-title").children('label').each(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");
        context.font = $(this).css('font-style') + " " + $(this).css('font-size') + " " + $(this).css('font-family');
        context.textAlign = $(this).css('text-align');
        context.fillStyle = $(this).css('color');
        context.fillText($(this).text(),
            newCanvas.width / 2,
            offset.top - baseOffset.top + $(this).height() - 35
        );
    });

    // add the sub-title
    $('#'+pElementID).children("div.jqplot-title").children('span').each(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");
        context.font = $(this).css('font-style') + " " + $(this).css('font-size') + " " + $(this).css('font-family');
        context.textAlign = $(this).css('text-align');
        context.fillStyle = $(this).css('color');
        context.fillText($(this).text(),
            newCanvas.width / 2,
            offset.top - baseOffset.top + ($(this).height() * 2) - 30
        );
    });
    // add the legend
    $('#'+pElementID).children("table.jqplot-table-legend").each(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");
        //Commented to remove the outline on legend
//        context.strokeStyle = $(this).css('border-top-color');
//        context.strokeRect(
//            offset.left - baseOffset.left,
//            offset.top - baseOffset.top,
//            $(this).width(),$(this).height()
//        );
        context.fillStyle = $(this).css('background-color');
        context.fillRect(
            offset.left - baseOffset.left,
            offset.top - baseOffset.top - 10,
            $(this).width(),$(this).height() 
        );
    });
    // add the rectangles
    $('#'+pElementID).find("div.jqplot-table-legend-swatch").each(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");
        context.fillStyle = $(this).css('background-color');
        context.fillRect(
            offset.left - baseOffset.left,
            offset.top - baseOffset.top,
            $(this).parent().width(),$(this).parent().height()
        );
    });
    $('#'+pElementID).find("td.jqplot-table-legend").each(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");
        context.font = $(this).css('font-style') + " " + $(this).css('font-size') + " " + $(this).css('font-family');
        context.fillStyle = $(this).css('color');
        context.textAlign = $(this).css('text-align');
        context.textBaseline = $(this).css('vertical-align');
        context.fillText($(this).text(),
            offset.left - baseOffset.left,
            offset.top - baseOffset.top + $(this).height()/2 + parseInt($(this).css('padding-top').replace('px',''))
        );
    });


    // convert the image to base64 format
    return newCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.99);
}
```